# Bootstrap Multiselect: How to change filterBehavior from value to text

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How to change filterBehavior from value to text for following multiselect?

```
$('#departmentid').multiselect({
    buttonWidth: '267px ',
    dropRight: true,
    inheritClass: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    filterBehavior: 'value',
    filterPlaceholder: 'Search Department...',
    maxHeight: 200,
    includeSelectAllOption: true
});
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @parkash kumar you know about bootstrap multiselect

Comment: Yes, but what is the issue you are having with it?

Comment: @parkash kumar   Ok...My issue is,,, we can use filterBehaviour by option name or text....

Comment: There are two possibilities of filter, we can filter options by their text and value. I don't understand why are you getting confused between option name / text?

Comment: Why not show what you mean using fiddlejs

Comment: OK....I got the answer...Thanks to all

Comment: @Parkash Kumar i have another doubt....When i click select all option the dropdown is not closed... If we can set any close button for dropdown close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The options are filtered based on their text (default). This behavior
>   can be changed to use the value of the options or both the text and
>   the value.

Therefore, you can change the `filterBehavior="text"` to filter options by option text / name or just remove that property, as following:

```
$('#departmentid').multiselect({
    buttonWidth: '267px ',
    dropRight: true,
    inheritClass: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    filterBehavior: 'text',
    filterPlaceholder: 'Search Department...',
    maxHeight: 200,
    includeSelectAllOption: true
});
```

[**Reference**](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-filterBehavior)

Comment: i have another doubt....When i click select all option the dropdown is not closed... If we can set any close button for dropdown close

Comment: If you have different question, you can use "Ask Question" button or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask